# How can I see the Tables and Values of my database?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I made a new ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio.
It created a database with tabels automatically for me.
Now I want to be able to change the database, where can I do this? I've been searching in the Server Explorer but can't seem to find anything.
Let me know if I need to provide some content of certain files for you to be able to answer this question.

Comment: You have just scratched the surface. Go to http://asp.net and check out the sample, especially the ones with Entity Framework to learn how to communicate with a database from your web application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, you can change your database connection in your connectionstring. Change your web.config file to the new database.

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=NEWDATABASESE-RVER-IP,PORT; Initial Catalog=DATABASE_NAME; UID=USERNAME; pwd=PASSWORD; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

[More information about connectionstring(s)](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Comment: I am aware of this but I don't want to change the database I just want to be able to see the tabels of the database that was created for me, the localdb.

Comment: do you have a database like mssql? -> MS Sql Management Studio or if you have created a mdf file.. this is in your APP_DATA Folder.. -> Double Click and you can see your data with SQL-Data-Tools from Visual Studio..

Comment: Thanks! An other question, can I start using an external database with sql server or do I need to start a new Project? That would be a bit unfirtunate since I am half way through my project already.

Comment: If you wanna change the Database, you only have to change the connectionstring like in my answer..Attention you will lose your DataBase-Data. When you start your Project, it will create the new database on your SQL Server (Code_First)

Comment: I am not sure if the application will still work if I use an other database. Should the database have the same tabels and fields, etc.?

Comment: it will create the same tables and fields, but only without Data

Comment: So if I create an External DB with sql server and link it with the right connectio string everything will work, but I will lose the data in the tabels?

Comment: jap. the data are actually in your APP_DATA/myDatabyse.mdf-File. At the first start/data accses, entity-framework, will create your database and the new tables on your sql-server

Comment: How can I make sure I am using the external database now?

Comment: rename your mdf-File or check with MS Sql Management Studio.

Comment: So in MS SQL qerver management studio I login with the server name and Windows Authentication -> I create a new databe named "testdb" 
What is the username and password for the connectionstring?

Comment: I've tried this "<add name="MyDbConn1" connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"/>" but doesnt seem to work since my data is still visible